# How-To Update Python 3.x When the New Version Rolled - Out on macOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, macos-high-sierra

I installed Python 3.6.5 on macOS. How can I update Python When the new version rolled out ? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do have the latest version of python3

You can use **homebrew** to update python

To **install** **homebrew**

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

To **install python** (if not installed)

```
brew install python3
```

Finally, **update the python** (this is what you are looking for)

```
brew upgrade python3
```

Nice explanation here - 
 https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/201612/keeping-python-3-up-to-date-on-a-mac